# In MVC.NET project, changing .aspx HTML content does not update site while debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on an existing MVC3 project, in VS 2010. The site is running in debug mode, using the VS development server. It's all working ok, but if I make a change to the home page, in Index.aspx, the change does not appear on the web site, unless I stop and restart the project.

I'm new to MVC.NET, so not sure if this is by design. I'm used to a normal web project, where editing an aspx file will have immediate effect if you refresh the page in the browser.

It is really necessary to restart debugging for MVC to recognise a change to an aspx file? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: You dont have to restart the debugging for it to take effect. A refresh on the browser should do.

Comment: But build the project first.

Comment: Thanks, yep made sure project was built in debug prior to running. Refresh as I may, the HTML change just doesn't appear unless I restart it.